# What is the most efficient way to paste strings in R?

Tags: r, performance, paste

I have two very large vectors that I need to concatenate with a delimiter to form unique IDs. For example:

```
set.seed(1)

vec1 <- sample(1:10, 10000000, replace = T)
vec2 <- sample(1:1000000000, 10000000)
```

I am currently using `paste0()`:

```
system.time({    
  uniq_id <- paste0(vec1, "_", vec2)
})
```

However, due to the size of `vec1` and `vec2` this is quite slow. Is there an alternate method with greater performance?

Comment: I haven't tested this but the `glue` package claims to be faster than `paste0`: Here is a benchmark ... https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glue/vignettes/speed.html

Comment: sorry I actually read that wrong - that was evals per sec in that table so `paste0` is faster than all the other things tried in that table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more efficient way is `stringi::stri_c`

```
library(microbenchmark)
b <- microbenchmark(
  paste = paste0(vec1, "_", vec2),
  stringi = stringi::stri_c(vec1, vec2, sep = "_"),
  times = 10
)
```

Result

```
b
#Unit: seconds
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   paste 5.475398 5.509957 5.544477 5.542728 5.566904 5.632173    10   b
# stringi 3.862541 3.871826 3.896242 3.897264 3.914894 3.934175    10  a
```

Answer (score 3):

Comparing `paste`, `paste0` (R version 4.1.0 ), `stringi::stri_c` (Version 1.6.2) and `stringr::str_c` (Version 1.4.0) I could not observe much difference in performance but maybe this will depend on what will be concatenated. There is much difference if numbers or characters are used and if the characters consists of numbers or letters. When there are only letters stringi and stringr seams to be faster than paste.

```
M <- alist(
    paste0 = paste0(vec1, "_", vec2)
  , paste = paste(vec1, "_", vec2, sep = "")
  , pasteS = paste(vec1, vec2, sep = "_")
  , stringi = stringi::stri_c(vec1, "_", vec2)
  , stringiS = stringi::stri_c(vec1, vec2, sep = "_")
  , stringr = stringr::str_c(vec1, "_", vec2)
  , stringrS = stringr::str_c(vec1, vec2, sep = "_")
)
```

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e5
vec1 <- sample(1:10, n, TRUE)
vec2 <- sample(1:1000000000, n, TRUE)
bench::mark(exprs = M)
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 paste0      62.8ms  63.9ms      15.6    2.29MB     2.23     7     1      447ms
#2 paste       61.9ms    63ms      15.9    2.29MB     0        8     0      503ms
#3 pasteS      57.5ms  58.6ms      17.1    2.29MB     2.13     8     1      468ms
#4 stringi     57.1ms  57.6ms      17.2    2.29MB     0        9     0      524ms
#5 stringiS    56.2ms  66.2ms      14.4    2.29MB     2.40     6     1      417ms
#6 stringr     57.9ms  62.9ms      14.8    2.29MB     0        8     0      541ms
#7 stringrS      55ms  61.4ms      15.3    2.29MB     0        8     0      523ms

vec1 <- as.character(vec1)
vec2 <- as.character(vec2)
bench::mark(exprs = M)
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 paste0      34.2ms  35.3ms      28.2     781KB     2.17    13     1      460ms
#2 paste       35.1ms  35.7ms      27.9     781KB     0       14     0      502ms
#3 pasteS        32ms  33.5ms      29.9     781KB     2.14    14     1      468ms
#4 stringi     33.7ms  35.6ms      28.1     781KB     0       15     0      534ms
#5 stringiS    32.6ms  33.9ms      29.6     781KB     2.12    14     1      472ms
#6 stringr     34.6ms  34.9ms      28.5     781KB     0       15     0      526ms
#7 stringrS    33.1ms  33.4ms      29.7     781KB     2.12    14     1      471ms
```

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e5
vec1 <- as.character(sample(0:9, n, TRUE))
vec2 <- as.character(sample(0:9, n, TRUE))
bench::mark(exprs = M)
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 paste0      18.9ms    19ms      52.4     781KB     2.02    26     1      496ms
#2 paste       18.9ms    19ms      52.5     781KB     0       27     0      514ms
#3 pasteS      15.2ms  15.3ms      65.3     781KB     2.04    32     1      490ms
#4 stringi     15.1ms  15.1ms      65.7     781KB     0       33     0      502ms
#5 stringiS    13.5ms  13.5ms      73.7     781KB     2.05    36     1      489ms
#6 stringr     15.1ms  15.2ms      65.7     781KB     2.05    32     1      487ms
#7 stringrS    13.4ms  13.5ms      73.3     781KB     0       37     0      505ms
```

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e5
vec1 <- paste(sample(0:9, n, TRUE))
vec2 <- paste(sample(0:9, n, TRUE))
bench::mark(exprs = M)
  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 paste0     18.95ms 19.18ms      52.1     781KB     0       27     0      518ms
#2 paste      18.78ms 18.98ms      52.6     781KB     2.02    26     1      494ms
#3 pasteS     14.29ms 14.49ms      69.0     781KB     0       35     0      508ms
#4 stringi      9.6ms  9.83ms     101.      781KB     2.02    50     1      495ms
#5 stringiS    7.55ms  7.73ms     127.      781KB     2.01    63     1      496ms
#6 stringr     9.58ms  9.75ms     101.      781KB     2.03    50     1      493ms
#7 stringrS    7.54ms  7.77ms     127.      781KB     2.02    63     1      496ms
```

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e5
vec1 <- sample(letters, n, TRUE)
vec2 <- sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE)
bench::mark(exprs = M)
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 paste0     15.98ms 16.02ms      61.5     781KB     2.05    30     1      488ms
#2 paste      16.02ms 16.09ms      62.1     781KB     2.07    30     1      483ms
#3 pasteS     11.96ms 12.03ms      83.0     781KB     2.02    41     1      494ms
#4 stringi     7.97ms  8.07ms     123.      781KB     4.18    59     2      478ms
#5 stringiS    6.37ms  6.43ms     154.      781KB     4.12    75     2      486ms
#6 stringr     7.97ms  8.02ms     124.      781KB     2.04    61     1      491ms
#7 stringrS    6.43ms  6.49ms     153.      781KB     4.09    75     2      489ms
```

The differences depend on how the `character` is internal stored. Either as `CHARSXP` or `REALSXP` or `INTSXP`.

```
x <- as.character(1:2)
.Internal(inspect(x))
#@55d9df5270d8 16 STRSXP g0c0 [REF(1)]   <deferred string conversion>
#  @55d9df527180 13 INTSXP g0c0 [REF(65535)]  1 : 2 (compact)

x <- as.character(c(0,2))
.Internal(inspect(x))
#@55d9df5430a0 16 STRSXP g0c0 [REF(1)]   <deferred string conversion>
#  @55d9df6720a8 14 REALSXP g0c2 [REF(65535)] (len=2, tl=0) 0,2

x <- paste(1:2)
.Internal(inspect(x))
#@55d9df610d08 16 STRSXP g0c2 [REF(1)] (len=2, tl=0)
#  @55d9d2e30458 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,REF(40995),gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "1"
#  @55d9d2e58b00 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,REF(40555),gp=0x60] [ASCII] [cached] "2"

x <- letters[1:2]
.Internal(inspect(x))
#@55d9df672168 16 STRSXP g0c2 [REF(1)] (len=2, tl=0)
#  @55d9d2c80518 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,REF(541),gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "a"
#  @55d9d2fb7d58 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,REF(44),gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "b"
```